# Same script php on localhost doesn´t work online

Tags: php, sql, database

My php script is working on localhost, otherwise it´s not working online (web hosting)

The php versions are the same and the SQL as well

I don´t know what´s wrong with it:

```
    <?php

error_log();

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db   = 'controleestoque';

// conexão e seleção do banco de dados
$con = mysqlI_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

// GET ID
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
    $idUsuario = $_GET['id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario = '$idUsuario'";
    $qr = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    $ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr);

    $nomeUsuario = $ln['nomeUsuario'];
    $celularUsuario = $ln['celularUsuario'];
    $emailUsuario = $ln['emailUsuario'];
    $dataBoleto = date("Y-m-d");
    $tipoPlano = "planoPrata";
    $valorBoleto = "120,00";


    /* Verifica se já tem um ID Boleto Repetido */
    while(true){

    $idBoleto = rand(1, 99999999999);
    $res = "SELECT * FROM boleto WHERE idBoleto = '$idBoleto'";
    $search = mysqli_query($con, $res);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($search) == 0){
    break;
    }
}

    /* Se não retornar com ID Boleto igual -> Continua */

    $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO boleto (idBoleto, tipoPlano, valorBoleto, idUsuario, nomeUsuario, celularUsuario, emailUsuario, dataBoleto) values ('$idBoleto', '$tipoPlano', '$valorBoleto', '$idUsuario', '$nomeUsuario', '$celularUsuario', '$emailUsuario', '$dataBoleto')");

    header("Location:gerar_boletoPrata.php?id=$idBoleto");

 } /* Termina Isset Get ID */

 else {
     echo "
            <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index1.php' />
            <script type='text/javascript'>alert ('Você precisa estar logado para visualizar esta página!!')</script>
     ";
     }
// END
?>
```

The error is: doesn´t insert on database and doesn´t show the right $idBoleto for the user

Could anyone help me here???

Comment: Here is some help:  (1) Stop using "mysql_"; it has been obsoleted; (2) Always use parameters to pass user input into queries.

Comment: What  does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Error messages? Server crashes? Computer caught on fire?

Comment: Hey Anthony, quick question have you made sure that the connection.php have the correct info?
that you are using the correct host, user, password and database?

Comment: What if you change `<?` to `<?php` ?

Comment: As Gordon says you should look into prepared statements using placeholders this also secures your site from sql injection. 
for documentation visit
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping your user inputs. You can use Prepared Statements if you use MySQLi or PDO (which you REALLY should).

Comment: I have not learned yet MySQLi or PDO. I´m trying to finish this project to go on with my learning

Comment: The short tags are working on the other functions of the site

Comment: The error is: doesn´t insert on database and doesn´t show the right $idBoleto for the user

Comment: the connetion.php is working right with the other site requirements, then this should be working as well

Comment: "I haven't learnt yet"  is never an excuse to, knowingly, use old, deprecated and insecure features. It's better to learn the correct way from the beginning.

Comment: I started with the MySQL and not MySQLi or PDO, but I will learn soon, I just wanted to know what´s the reason for not working this script

Comment: missing`$con` in the insert query

Comment: nogad, THANK YOU VERY MUCH. Could please put as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never passed the connection to this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO boleto ... ");
```

Therefore:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO boleto ... ");
```

and check for errors on all queries:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

You're also open to a serious sql injection; use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

It's also best to add `exit;` after header.

```
header("Location:gerar_boletoPrata.php?id=$idBoleto");
exit;
```

Otherwise, your code may want to continue to execute.

- Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also note that `mysqli_error()` requires a db connection as an argument.

- mysqli_error($con)

As per [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php):

> string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )

---

**Footnotes:**

I suggest you use `mysqli_connect` in all lowercase letters, instead of `mysqlI_connect` as the uppercase `I` (i) could be a distraction.

Comment: all yours buddy :-)

Comment: Cheers @nogad ;-)